# Symbols (from Django view) replaced with HTML entities

Tags: jquery, django, utf-8

I'm reading a set of rows from a database (through Django view), and I'm sending them to a Django template. In my view:

```
def get_rows(request, epNum):

    # Getting rows from the database,
    #
    allStatements = all_statements.objects.all()            

    template = loader.get_template('main/show_db_content.html')

    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'allStatements': allStatements,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

However, when I print the content of the rows (field is `CharField`), symbols (such as `<`) gets converted to their HTML entities equivalent! In my template:

```
<script>
    var all_rows = [];

    {% for el in allStatements %}
        all_rows.push('{{ el.text_content }}'); // text_content is type CharField
    {% endfor %}

    console.log(all_rows[0])
</script>
```

For example, if there was `<<` in my database, the output would be `&lt;&lt;`

**Apparently, I made some folks (comments below) really mad for not clearly stating my question, which I will have to admit was, to some extent, my fault...**

My question is: how can I avoid this conversion from symbols to HTML entities, I would like to print the symbol as it is instead of its HTML entity equivalent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter

BTW. You can shorten your code by using the [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut

Comment: Great! That did it; I'll check at the `render` shortcut. Thanks :)